# firefox ios remove popup animation or fix cursor misaligned

Tags: ios, iphone, firefox, popup

in IOS firefox, I have a login popup, but the cursor is misaligned, is outside the input. so I wanna remove the animation in the popup, or fix the misalignment. I'm not adding the animation, and I dont see that in any other browser.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, this is a common issue in firefox, in IOS.

So, my solution was increase the popup size to 100% and position top: 0px; left: 0px, this in mobiles is a good solution.